# select multiple ranges of columns in data.table using column names

Tags: r, data.table

I can select **multiple** ranges of columns in a data.table using a numeric vector like `c(1:5,27:30)`. Is there any way to do the same with column names? For example, in some form similar to `col1:col5,col27:col30`?

Comment: You would make this easier to answer by making an example. The `col1:col5` syntax can appear in a couple places and I don't know which you mean.

Comment: data.table[,col1:col5] -- this is the only context I am referring to if that helps

Comment: `select(df, col1:col5, col27:col30)` using `dplyr` library will do the job

Answer (score 2):

You can with `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6, g=7)
dplyr::select(df, a:c, f:g)

a b c f g
1 2 3 6 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my answer is efficient, but I think that could give you a workaround at least in case you need to work with `data.table`.
My proposal is to use `data.table` in conjunction with `cbind`. Thus you could have:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6, g=7)
multColSelectedByName<- cbind(df[,a:c],df[,f:g])
#a b c f g
#1: 1 2 3 6 7
```

One point that one should be careful is that if there is only one column in one of the selections, for example `df[,f]` then the name of this column would be something like `V2` and not `f`. In such a case one could use:
`multColSelectedByName<- cbind(df[,a:c],f=df[,f])`

Comment: This is the temporary solution I've been using, but thanks for the input.