# Select multiple ranges of columns using column names in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let say I have a data table,

```
dt = data.table(matrix(1:50, nrow = 5));
colnames(dt) = letters[1:10];

> dt
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
1: 1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
2: 2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47
3: 3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
4: 4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49
5: 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

I want to select several discontinuous ranges of columns like: `a`, `c:d`, `f:h` and `j`. This can be done easily via **dplyr's** `select()`:

`dt %>% select(a, c:d, f:h, j)`

I am looking for a **`data.table`** way of achieving the same.

Right now, I can either select columns individually in any order: `dt[ , .(a, c)]` or giving just *one* sequence of column names on the form `startcol:endcol`:

`dt[ , c:f]`

However, I can't combine the above two methods to select *several* column ranges in one shot in `.SDcols`, like I did in `dplyr::select`

Comment: Try `dt[, c(list(a= a), .SD) , .SDcols = c:d]`

Comment: @akrun Thanks! It seems to work and I can easily generalize is to my case.

Comment: @akrun Edited the question with further details.

Comment: Please check if the updated solution works for you

Comment: See also [select multiple ranges of columns in data.table using column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259737/select-multiple-ranges-of-columns-in-data-table-using-column-names)

Comment: @akrun `select()` inside `dt` looks concise and meaningful. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the range part in `.SDcols` and then append the other column by concatenating

```
dt[, c(list(a= a), .SD) , .SDcols = c:d]
```

---

If there are multiple ranges, we create a sequence of ranges by `match`, and then get the corresponding column names

```
i1 <- match(c("c", "f"), names(dt))
j1 <- match(c("d", "h"), names(dt))
nm1 <- c("a", names(dt)[unlist(Map(`:`, i1, j1))], "j")
dt[, ..nm1]
#   a  c  d  f  g  h  j
#1: 1 11 16 26 31 36 46
#2: 2 12 17 27 32 37 47
#3: 3 13 18 28 33 38 48
#4: 4 14 19 29 34 39 49
#5: 5 15 20 30 35 40 50
```

Also, the `dplyr` methods can be used within the `data.table`

```
dt[, select(.SD, a, c:d, f:h, j)]
#   a  c  d  f  g  h  j
#1: 1 11 16 26 31 36 46
#2: 2 12 17 27 32 37 47
#3: 3 13 18 28 33 38 48
#4: 4 14 19 29 34 39 49
#5: 5 15 20 30 35 40 50
```

Comment: Just wondering how would the above approach work with multiple sets of groupings: `dt = data.table(matrix(1:50, nrow = 5)); colnames(dt) = letters[1:10];` And I want to select columns: `a`, `c:d`, `g:h` and `j`. Any ideas?

Comment: which way is the preferred to select multiple range of columns? The unlist/Map or dplyr::select?

Comment: @EKtheSage `select` have more options

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround with `cbind` and two or more selections.

```
cbind(dt[, .(a)], dt[, c:d])
#    a  c  d
# 1: 1 11 16
# 2: 2 12 17
# 3: 3 13 18
# 4: 4 14 19
# 5: 5 15 20
```